Sourcing ~/.bashrc doesn't source included script
I've a Docker image that installs rvm. In the Dockerfile, I append the following lines to the ~/.bashrc of the user.
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin"
source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"

I also make bash act as the login shell.
SHELL ["/bin/bash", "-lc"]

Later, I create a container using Docker Compose, and run a shell script as the user in question.
entrypoint:
  - /bin/bash
  - '-lc'
command:
  - ~/.local/bin/ci

In the script ci, if I do source ~/.bashrc, the script can't find the rvm executable. However, if I specifically source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm", script runs successfully.
My question is, the .rvm/scripts is part of the .bashrc, so, why does sourcing .bashrc doesn't work?

Don't try to use login shells to run scripts -- leads to confusion like this. Leave the -l off (aside: being a login script makes it source .bash_profile not .bashrc) and write your code explicitly. Beyond that -- add -x to get a log of execution so you can see what it and isn't happening.

@CharlesDuffy What do you mean by “write your code explicitly”? Also, login shell or not, if .bashrc is explicitly sourced, it should work.

You should be able to build your image FROM ruby:3.3.5 or whatever other version you need.  I'd try to avoid version managers like rvm in a container, since the image never needs more than one version available, and you run into problems like this.

@DavidMaze I’m using rvm deliberately because that’s what my cloud hosting provider does in their Docker image. I want to keep the build logic as similar to theirs as possible to avoid the “works on my machine” problem (it did happen a few times).

Since you are using -l, your .bashrc does not get sourced.

@user1934428 That’s completely incorrect. The accepted answer explains why .bashrc isn’t sourced.

The rules whether .bashrc is or is not processed on startup, are a bit convoluated (see the section INVOCATION in the bash man-page), but  a simple and safe way to prohibit .bashrc to be read, is to use the --norc option, i.e. SHELL ["/bin/bash", "-lc", "--norc"]

You didn’t post your full .bashrc, but from your bash -x output it’s clear that your .bashrc is checking for an interactive session with code like
case $- in
    *i*) ;;
      *) return;;
esac

This is a standard check which prevents .bashrc from taking effect in non-interactive shells. The sourced .bashrc returns before it executes any further commands (including the ones you added).
To avoid this, you could add your code above these lines so it will be executed even in a non-interactive context. However, a better solution would be to explicitly source a new file instead to avoid fiddling with .bashrc and friends.

That makes complete sense, thanks. As I mentioned in my answer, the .profile works for my purpose, presumably because it doesn’t have the interactive check.

As other commenters pointed out: it is still very fragile to rely on the behaviour of the login or interactive shell, especially for something like CI usage. The shell is specifically designed for batch use without the -l or -i flags. Maybe this is what will work for you, but for future readers: prefer non-interactive bash in any automation context.

Point taken, but since I don't know the installation path of the RVM, I can't source the script directly. That said, I've removed the somewhat obscure reliance on running the CI script with bash login, and instead explicitly sourced the .profile in it.

Running the CI script with -x showed that the .bashrc is indeed sourced, so, why the last statement in it didn't work I've no idea. I ended up appending source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm to the ~/.profile (instead of .bashrc), and running the CI script with a #!/bin/bash -l shebang. That seemed to have solved the executable not found problem, although the original question I asked remains unanswered.
-x trace:
+ '[' '' ']'
+ '[' -d /etc/profile.d ']'
+ for i in /etc/profile.d/*.sh
+ '[' -r /etc/profile.d/01-locale-fix.sh ']'
+ . /etc/profile.d/01-locale-fix.sh
+++ /usr/bin/locale-check C.UTF-8
++ eval 'LANG='\''C.UTF-8'\'''
+++ LANG=C.UTF-8
+ unset i
+ '[' -n '5.0.17(1)-release' ']'
+ '[' -f /home/jekyll/.bashrc ']'
+ . /home/jekyll/.bashrc
++ case $- in
++ return
+ '[' -d /home/jekyll/bin ']'
+ '[' -d /home/jekyll/.local/bin ']'
+ PATH=/home/jekyll/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
+ /home/jekyll/.local/bin/ci


The case $- in and return is the crucial evidence here. BTW, you could make this more readable with PS4=':$BASH_SOURCE:$LINENO+' so each log line tells you which file that command came from; that way you could see when execution moves between files (so the fact that the return is preventing a file from continuing to execute would be more obvious as a reader).
